# Creating a GodRays effect pass for Effect Composer

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying to move the god-rays demo code into an effect pass to use in the effect composer so that its easier to use with other post-processing effects.
The render function of the effect is not getting called though...

I'm creating the pass in the format:

```
THREE.GodRaysPass = function ( width, height, camera, renderer, scene) {

//setup code};

THREE.GodRaysPass.prototype = {

render: function ( renderer, writeBuffer, readBuffer, delta, maskActive ) {

//render code

}};
```

And initialising:

```
this.composer = new THREE.EffectComposer( this.renderer );
    var effectGodRays = new THREE.GodRaysPass(this.width, this.height, this.camera, this.renderer, this.scene);
    this.composer.addPass( effectGodRays );
```

Comment: Are you calling composer.render(); in your render loop?

Comment: Yes, if I add other passes they render

Comment: Can you share the code please? I'm trying to do the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EffectComposer checks for 'enabled' property before rendering. Switch to true :-)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Each effect needs to have a property called 'enabled' on it. This property needs to be set to true or the composer will ignore it. Pretty sure this answers the question